# how to trigger the build of a node module? postinstall does not work

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a package.json with a dependency having a github-url:

`"dependencies": {
        "my_dependency": "git+https://github.com/gitrepo.git#mybranch"
}`

Now the problem is that this dependency needs to get built after being downloaded from github. So I have added a postinstall-instruction to package.json of the dependency.

Well, it does get triggered when I go explicitly to this dependency project in the node_modules-folder and type: npm install.
But unfortunately it does not get triggered when running npm install in the parent project directory.

How do I trigger a build within a dependency in npm?
There is a use case such as here....when you have a dependency which is not in the npm registry but on github. You usually dont commit the build files. So you need to produce the build files after downloading them.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide the post-install script?
Else you can try out:

```
"scripts": {
   "postinstall": "node ./node_modules/<path> make"
}
```

Comment: Trying to execute gulp in the postinstall...But the command gulp could not be found. even though I have added it into the devdepenecies section in the package.json of the dependency. But it causes an error claiming that gulp command is not found

Comment: But why are you trying to run gulp from a project that is yet to build?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this won't work for non npm dependencies like your github link there. This worked for me though: https://github.com/exogen/postinstall-build